# Method's parameters: a way to know a uint256 is a token amount and its number of decimals?

Tags: tokens, abi, logs, decoding

When decoding transaction actions or logs, I never know how to human-read `uint256` values when they are token amounts and, if so, how to know how many decimals they are.

For the decimals, do I always have to know which token the amount parameter is associated to and call its `decimals()` method?

Answer (score 0):

Uint256 is a kind of number but it is only ready to be displayed as string.

So in the case of using Javascript, you can try `.toString()` then call `Number([toString's output])` to get a decimal value.